# What kind of completely online business can I run doing infosec/cyber security?

Tags: business-risk

I have been working in the field the past 2-3 years and I have a total of 10 years experience with computer science. I want something I could do part time from any country in the world. I would rather not do straight coding, either. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Go bug bounty hunting.**

Participating in companies' [bug bounty programs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bug_bounty_program) is something you

- can do part-time (in fact, whenever you like),
- doesn't require your physical presence anywhere and
- certainly isn't coding only.

One way to get started is by creating an account at a bug hunting platform such as [Bugcrowd](https://bugcrowd.com/list-of-bug-bounty-programs) or [HackerOne](https://www.hackerone.com/) where you can find tons of companies that offer monetary rewards for reporting vulnerabilities in their products and services. Or you can directly check out individual vulnerability reward programs, such as the ones of [Google](https://www.google.com/about/appsecurity/reward-program/) and [PayPal](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/security-tools/reporting-security-issues).

(The bug hunting community has grown significantly in recent years, so being able to compete will require you some creativity and thorough knowledge of the technologies you're pentesting, though.)

Answer (score 0):

How about consultancy? Especially to the small and medium sized companies. They tend to want people for a days cyber training and are less demanding around schedules than larger organisations.

One area in the Europe that's very hot with the SMB market is GDPR

Comment: But how would that work from remote?

Comment: Delivered using the likes of WebEx is a possibility. We've worked with many consultants who are part time and easily contactable to deliver training or support sessions on projects we have worked on. They seem to love the freedom it offers.